# iOS - How To Show A Custom Pop-up View On A Preferred Position In UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface

[image]

I have a view controller that displays a bunch of buttons for music control. One of them is a volume control located at the button. I wish to display a mini pop-up view that contains just a vertical slider when the volume control button is clicked. How can I achieve this?

The first solution that came up on my mind is setting a slider that is hidden initially, and will be shown after the button is clicked. But I don't want this solution. I want a more "professional" way. I also searched through the net about pop up views, most of them are something like a custom alert dialog in which the background is dimmed, and I don't want that.

So please help me if you can. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: Hi @Ashish Kakkad. Well, I don't even have a clue on how to do this. Like what I mentioned above, I thought of hiding and showing. But I don't want that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
       [super viewDidLoad];
       popupView.hidden=YES;
}
```

this code place in Show Slider button Click event

```
[self showSliderPopup];// call method
popupView.hidden=NO;
```

create popup method

```
-(void) showSliderPopup{
    UISlider *slider=[[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 300)];
    CGAffineTransform trans=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
    slider.transform=trans;
    slider.minimumValue=1;
    slider.maximumValue=100;
    slider.continuous=NO;
    [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanhge:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

   popupView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 350)]; // set popup frame your require position 
    [popupView addSubview:slider];
    [self.view addSubview:popupView];
}
```

Slider Change method

```
-(IBAction)sliderChanhge:(id)sender
{
     NSLog(@"%d",(int)slider.value);
}
```

Comment: I can't move the thumb of the slider

Comment: CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 350) set frame bigger then slider @EpicNinja